# How can I return parameters in Jenkins pipeline based upon the job name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins pipeline (a)`deploy` and (b)`test_deploy`. I want to run both these pipeline from **one Jenkinsfile** as there functionality is same.

- `deploy` pipeline runs on for all non-test environments
- `test_deploy` pipeline will run only on `test` environments

I want to only show test environments as parameters in `test_deploy` pipeline. *I want to add something like if/else conditions on choice parameters that will return environment names in parameters based upon the job name.* How can I condition choice/parameters based upon job name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this at the top of your Jenkinsfile:

```
if (JOB_NAME == 'deploy') {
    properties([
        parameters([
            choice(name: 'deployEnv', choices: ['deployEnv1', 'deployEnv2'], description: '')
        ])
    ])
} else if (JOB_NAME == 'test_deploy') {
    properties([
        parameters([
            choice(name: 'testEnv', choices: ['testEnv1', 'testEnv2'], description: '')
        ])
    ])
}
```

This works in both Declarative and Scripted Pipelines, and populates the choice parameters based on the job names.